# Change style of the image that has a certain size

Tags: css

How do i, change the size of picture that their size more than a certain size with css . For example, how do i change the appearance of photos that their width is more than 300 pixels.

Comment: For future reader's ease: he means he wants to apply different styling to an image, depending on it's source size. Kind of like media queries, but instead of looking at the image dimensions instead of the page's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some basic info on working with images:

http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_images.asp

## Some possible ways to resize images:

Either style the image through css:

```
img {
  width:200%;
}
```

Or do so with inline css

```
<img style="width:500px;" src="..."/>
```

or use HTML attributes

```
<img width="30px" height="auto" src="..."/>
```

As shown here you can use different kinds of units too. `px`, `%`, `em`, `rem`, `vw` & `vh` are some that are available.

## Media queries

If you want to apply different styles depending on the page size, use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

## Image-size dependent styling

If you want to apply different styling to your image depending on it's source size, I think you're out of luck. You can use javascript to do it, but as far as I know there isn't a pure CSS solution.

## Nota Bene

It should be noted, though, that your question raises the suspicion that you didn't even bother googling, as this is **absolutely basic** HTML / CSS.

Comment: tank you. but i want change style of images that their size is more than special size.

Comment: yes, i want to apply different styling to your image depending on it's source size

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [min](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) width/height and the [max](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) width/height:

Example:

```
p {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

If you want a more control u can use [media](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp):

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img_smallflower.jpg" media="(max-width: 400px)">
  <source srcset="img_flowers.jpg">
  <img src="img_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers">
</picture>
```

Comment: tank you. but this code change style of all image. but i want change style of images that their size is more than special size.